# posting an array of json using dojo

Tags: json, dojo

Hi I am trying to post an array of javascript objects back to the server, using dojo.

I have an array of data that is like appears like this:

```
var elements = [
  myobj = {id:"1", name:"myname", title:"mytitle"},
  myobj = {id:"2", name:"myname2", title:"mytitle2"}
]
```

I want to post this as a json string back to the server to be handled by a PHP script.  However dojo.toJson will only seralise an individual object.

How can I convert the entire array of objects into a json string that can be posted to the backend for processing?

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misinformed: `dojo.toJson()` handles arrays without a problem. I just plugged in your `elements` and that's what I've got:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"myname","title":"mytitle"},{"id":"2","name":"myname2","title":"mytitle2"}]
```

Looks okay to me.

But maybe I misunderstood something? Please post a sample proving your point.

Comment: No you're right... Where I was getting my information was from http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/toJson.html#dojo-tojson and it only gives you an object reference.  After trying again all seems well.

Thanks

Comment: Right. An array is an object too. Not all objects are that lucky: some objects like regular expressions, or dates are not supported by JSON directly. But an array is a fundamental part of JSON, so all libraries I know of handle arrays well.